# User Input Multiple Integer Variable Values in a Single Line (Java)

Tags: java, variables, integer

This is the output I'm trying to create:

Please enter food servings separated by a blank in the order

Vegetables & Fruit, Grain Products, Milk & Alt, Meat & Alt: 8 7 1 3

Food Group          Servings

Vegetables & Fruit     8

Grain Products         7

Milk & Alternatives    1

Meat & Alternatives    3

How can I accept multiple integers in the same line from user input, whilst assigning those integers to their own variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the input by spaces and assign them to their own variables

```
String input = blah;
String[] split = input.split("\\s+");

int veg = 0;
int milk = 0;
//add more variables

veg = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
milk = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
//add more stuff here
```

Comment: Lol, beat me to it :)

Comment: And what happens if the user only enters 2 values instead of 4 ? or enters :1 1w 4 8 ?